# Pivot Records in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My Current tables looks like this for 1 User.

```
NewCustomerID   OldCustomerID   RowID       Date
111               NULL             1        2016-01-01
222               111              321      2016-02-05
333               222              5433     2017-03-01
444               333              95312    2017-04-03
```

Table below is what I need for end result. Needs to be TSQL.

```
NewCustomerID   OldCustomerID   
 444               111            
 444               222              
 444               333
```

I will be using the table above to update all the OldCustomerID's to the latest  NewCustomerID

Comment: What is the logic by which `NewCustomerID` `444` became associated with every `OldCustomerID`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am guessing those are all the history ID that `444` used before

Comment: A Customer is being migrated from one location to another, so he's customerID keeps changing. Every time the customerID change there is a log of what it was and what it now is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a recursive cte:

```
with cte as (
      select t.NewCustomerID, t.OldCustomerID
      from t
      where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.OldCustomerId = t.NewCustomerID)
      union all
      select cte.NewCustomerId, t.OldCustomerID
      from cte join
           t
           on t.NewCustomerID = cte.OldCustomerID
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/VDULF42051) is an example of it working.

Comment: Hi Gordon, what is `1` from your first part of `union all`?  and seems number of columns does not match?

Comment: The above does not work for me, it does not return my end result as in my question :(

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @SampleDAta AS TABLE
(
    NewCustomerID   int,
    OldCustomerID   int
)
INSERT INTO @SampleDAta VALUES (111,  NULL),(222,111),(333,222),(444,333),(1111,  NULL),(2222,1111),(3333,2222),(4444,3333),(5555,4444)

;with reTbl as (
      select t.NewCustomerID, t.OldCustomerID, 1 as lev, t.NewCustomerID AS RootId
      from @SampleDAta t
      where t.OldCustomerID IS NULL
      union all
      select t.NewCustomerId, t.OldCustomerID, reTbl.lev +1, reTbl.RootId 
      from reTbl join
           @SampleDAta t
           on t.OldCustomerID = reTbl.NewCustomerID
     ),
LastestId AS
(
    SELECT c.RootId, max(c.lev) AS MaxLevel 
    FROM reTbl c 
    GROUP BY c.RootId
)

select reTbl.NewCustomerID, reTbl1.NewCustomerID AS OldCustomerID
from reTbl 
INNER JOIN reTbl reTbl1 ON reTbl.RootId = reTbl1.RootId
INNER JOIN LastestId t ON reTbl.RootId = t.RootId AND reTbl.lev = t.MaxLevel
WHERE reTbl.NewCustomerID != reTbl1.NewCustomerID
ORDER BY reTbl.NewCustomerID
```